# Want to increase lwc icon size in in specific pixels. so what i did is added style="size:50px" this is not worked for me

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system

This is the code.

```
 <lightning-button-icon style="size:50px" icon-name="utility:settings" variant="bare" alternative-text="Settings"
icon-class="slds-m-around_medium ">
```

Want to increase lwc icon size in in specific pixels. so what i did is added style="size:50px" this is not worked for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you'd use the size attribute but if you want it bigger or smaller then using the zoom CSS property is your next best option

```
 <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:travel_and_places" style="zoom: 400%"></lightning-icon>

<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:travel_and_places" style="zoom: 35%"></lightning-icon>
```

Comment: thanks Asheer...zoom CSS property worked fine...thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/specification), you have an attribute `size` with different sizing.

Comment: yes, but if I want to give a specific size like 50px, 120px then?